# MDN Docs function expression and function declaration good for debugging(?)

Tags: javascript, function

According to MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), you can use both a function declaration and function expression, because:

> However, a name can be provided with a function expression. Providing
> a name allows the function to refer to itself, and also makes it
> easier to identify the function in a debugger's stack traces:

The code:

```
const factorial = function fac(n) {
  return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);
};

console.log(factorial(3)); // 6
```

My question is:

- How would this make it easier to identify the function in debugger stack trace?
- A function can also refer to itself if it were to be one or the other.

So basically: What's the point of combining these 2? I simply cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: The function already has a name `fac`

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but what's the benefit of naming it "factorial" as well? What's the point of doing that, if I can refer to it by either factorial = function() ... or function fac() ... It doesn't make sense to me to have both factorial and fac

Comment: `factorial` makes more sense to write than `fac`

Answer (score 1):

> How would this make it easier to identify the function in debugger stack trace?

Because it lists the function in the stack trace as *fac* instead of (on of many) *anonymous function*s.

[image: Screenshot showing 'fac' in the stack trace]

---

> What's the point of combining these 2?

There's no benefit for using a local variable in the outer scope *and* a name for referencing the function in this example.

It appears to be a simplified example to demonstrate *how it works* and not *why it is useful*.

Consider if you are passing the function as an argument instead of assigning it to a variable.

```
 myArray.sort(function caseInsensitiveAlphaSort() { ... });
```

or using the function in a context where the `factorial` variable might be overwritten due to asynchronous shenanigans.

Comment: Why would a person opt to use this, rather then simply doing function fac()?

Comment: Okay, but the function you passed in as argument can also be annonymous, not? Or for that matter be defined as function x() and then passed in as myArray.sort(x)

Comment: "Okay, but the function you passed in as argument can also be annonymous, not?" — Yes … then it would be hard to identify in the stack trace. (and couldn't be called recursively).

Comment: "Or for that matter be defined as function x() and then passed in as myArray.sort(x)" — Then you're creating an extra variable in the current scope. Possibly even a global.

Comment: Your line of questioning really comes across as "Why would they give use a useful thing when we already have different useful things?". You're getting another useful thing! Be happy!

Answer (score 0):

1. Anonymous functions like arrow functions obfuscates the stack trace. So if you provide the name, it really is easier to debug because you see the name in stack trace.
2. And, using the name, the use of recursion will be easier - like you see there in MDN docs in that particular example you posted already!

Afaik those are the points for use that way to create a function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).